# Setting resource directory for ESAPI

Tags: java, properties, esapi

Working with OWASP's ESAPI, I found myself stuck at this particular line of code.

```
private static String customDirectory = System.getProperty("org.owasp.esapi.resources");
```

The code returns null as there is no such system property "org.owasp.esapi.resources" set on my computer. Is there any way to set this property on my computer permanently?

Comment: Can you specify what you're trying to do here? Are you trying to get the properties files in the resource directory or something?

Comment: actually I am unable to set the resource directory itself. I mean I don't know how to specify/configure the path to the resource directory. 

Until now, I was getting away by placing all the resources in .esapi directory as the code (last ditch effort) tries to get them from this folder located in user.home

Comment: What I've done before is created a package called resource at src/org/owasp/esapi/resources and put my ESAPI.properties and validtion.properties in there. Then I built the ESAPI Project. Once it was built, I took the jar file generated that was in the targets folder and then whenever I used it, the resources were loaded automatically from the resources folder I created earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass it into your JVM as a command line property. Most application containers use the environment variable JAVA_OPTS as a "permanent" store of options that should be passed to the JVM. You can try to do something like this:

In *nix:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dorg.owasp.esapi.resources=/path/to/esapi/configuration"
```

In windows:

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Dorg.owasp.esapi.resources=C:\path\to\esapi\configuration"
```

You can add this to windows or linux as a startup command and it will always be set if you desire, or add it to your application's startup script for a more localized solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the ESAPI.properties and Validation.properties inside the resources folder it will recognize automatically.

In case you need to specify s specific folder or sub-folders, one possibility is adding this property in your standalone.

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="org.owasp.esapi.resources" value="C:/.../resources/esapi"/>
<system-properties>
```

However, in unit tests, you have to specify before the tests.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void before() {    
   if(System.getProperty("org.owasp.esapi.resources") != null) {
      System.out.println(System.getProperty("org.owasp.esapi.resources"));
   } else  {
      System.setProperty("org.owasp.esapi.resources", "src/main/resources");
   }
}
```